# com.ibm.mq.MQException: MQJE001: Completion Code 2, Reason 2009 using Sprint Boot with JMS (IBM MQ )

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jms, ibm-mq, spring-jms

I am not sure what I am doing wrong, this issue is very sporadic, I have below code to send JMS Messages on IBM MQ. I am doing it in a seperate theread usign spring @async as below.

```
@Override
@Async
public void crewSeqAssignOrRemoveBatch(List<Batch> oBatchFosRequestList, String transactionType) throws InterruptedException {
    long lStartTime = Instant.now().toEpochMilli();
    logger.info("In Seperate Thread for FOS Submissoin, Thread Name is " + Thread.currentThread().getId() + ":"+Thread.currentThread().getName()+":"+Thread.currentThread().getThreadGroup()+":"+Thread.currentThread().activeCount()+":"+Thread.currentThread().getState());
    logger.info("FHSeqAssignOrRemoveServiceImpl : crewSeqAssignOrRemoveBatch() : Start >>");

    try
    {  
        for (Iterator<Batch> iterator = oBatchFosRequestList.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            Batch oBatchFosRequest = iterator.next();
            UUID uniqueId = UUID.randomUUID();
            String correlationId = uniqueId.toString() + "-" + oBatchFosRequest.getTransactionID() +"-"+ Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
            logger.info("correlationId generated is :" + correlationId);        
            try {
                        //JMSTextMessage message = null;

                         logger.info("Executing MessageCreator for ID "+ oBatchFosRequest.getTransactionID() +" on :" + new Date().toString()); 
                            MessageCreator mc = new MessageCreator() {

                                @Override
                                public Message createMessage(Session session) throws JMSException {

                                    JMSTextMessage message = null;

                                    try {
                                    logger.info("Executing CreateMessage for ID "+ oBatchFosRequest.getTransactionID() +" on :" + new Date().toString());   
                                    //POINT 2
                                    logger.info("Session Object ........ " + session.toString());
                                    logger.info("Session Status  - Is Session Transacted ?........ " + session.getTransacted());
                                    logger.info("Session Status acknowledge mode........ " + session.getAcknowledgeMode());
                                    logger.info("Ready to send message........ ");
                                    logger.info("Send ConnectionFactory is: " + jmsQueueTemplate.getConnectionFactory().toString());
                                    logger.info("Send destination is: " + jmsQueueTemplate.getDefaultDestination());
                                    logger.info("Reply destination is: " + destination);
                                    logger.info("Sent message correlationId is: " + correlationId);
                                    logger.info("##########################################################");
                                    message = (JMSTextMessage) session.createTextMessage();
                                    String fosXmlBatchRequest = XMLUtil.createBatchFosRequestXML(oBatchFosRequest);
                                    message.setText(fosXmlBatchRequest);
                                    message.setJMSCorrelationID(correlationId);
                                    logger.info(transactionType + " : Sending message is:");
                                    logger.info(message.getText());
                                    logger.info("##########################################################");
                                    message.setJMSReplyTo(destination);
                                    } catch (JMSException je) {



                                        Exception ex = je.getLinkedException();
                                        logger.info("JMS Linked Exception Occured :" + ex.getMessage());
                                        ex.printStackTrace();

                                        logger.info("JMS Exception Occured :" + je.getMessage());
                                        je.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                    catch (Exception e) {
                                        logger.info("Exception Occured :" + e.getMessage());
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                    return message;
                                }
                            };

                            logger.info("Executing send for ID "+ oBatchFosRequest.getTransactionID() +" on :" + new Date().toString());    
                            logger.info("Calling Send Method ");
                            jmsQueueTemplate.send(mc);
                            logger.info("Send Completed");
```

My JMS Cnfiguration is as below :

```
import javax.jms.Destination;
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import org.apache.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Configurable;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate;
import org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer;
import org.springframework.jms.support.converter.MappingJackson2MessageConverter;
import org.springframework.jms.support.converter.MessageConverter;
import org.springframework.jms.support.converter.MessageType;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueue;
import com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory;
@Configurable
@Component

public class JMSConfiguration {


private final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(JMSConfiguration.class);

@Autowired
MessageListenerReciever messageListenerReciever1;

@Autowired
MessageListenerReciever messageListenerReciever2;

private String hostName1;
private String hostName2;
private String hostName3;
private String writePort;
private String readPort;
private String channel;
private String transportType;
private String updateQueue;
private String replyQueue;
private String queueGateway;

@Autowired
JMSConfiguration(Environment environment){
    this.hostName1 = environment.getRequiredProperty("jms.cf.write.hostName1");
    this.hostName2 = environment.getRequiredProperty("jms.cf.read.hostName2");
    this.hostName3 = environment.getRequiredProperty("jms.cf.read.hostName3");
    this.writePort = environment.getRequiredProperty("jms.cf.write.port");
    this.readPort = environment.getRequiredProperty("jms.cf.read.port");
    this.channel = environment.getRequiredProperty("jms.cf.channel");
    this.transportType = environment.getRequiredProperty("jms.cf.transportType");
    this.updateQueue = environment.getRequiredProperty("jms.queue.update");
    this.replyQueue = environment.getRequiredProperty("jms.queue.reply");
    this.queueGateway = environment.getRequiredProperty("jms.queue.gateway");
}

@Bean
public MQQueueConnectionFactory connectionFactory1() {
    MQQueueConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new MQQueueConnectionFactory();
    try {
        connectionFactory.setHostName(hostName1);
        connectionFactory.setPort(Integer.parseInt(writePort));
        connectionFactory.setChannel(channel);
        connectionFactory.setTransportType(Integer.parseInt(transportType));
    } catch (NumberFormatException | JMSException e) {
        log.error(e.toString(),e);
    }
    return connectionFactory;
}


@Bean
@Primary
public CachingConnectionFactory cachingConnectionFactory(MQQueueConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    CachingConnectionFactory oCachingConnectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory();
    oCachingConnectionFactory.setTargetConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    //oCachingConnectionFactory.setCacheProducers(true);
    oCachingConnectionFactory.setSessionCacheSize(100);
    oCachingConnectionFactory.setReconnectOnException(true);
    return oCachingConnectionFactory;
}


public MQQueueConnectionFactory connectionFactory2() {
    MQQueueConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new MQQueueConnectionFactory();
    try {
        connectionFactory.setHostName(hostName2);
        connectionFactory.setPort(Integer.parseInt(readPort));
        connectionFactory.setChannel(channel);
        connectionFactory.setTransportType(Integer.parseInt(transportType));
    } catch (NumberFormatException | JMSException e) {
        log.error(e.toString(),e);
    }
    return connectionFactory;
}

public MQQueueConnectionFactory connectionFactory3() {
    MQQueueConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new MQQueueConnectionFactory();
    try {
        connectionFactory.setHostName(hostName3);
        connectionFactory.setPort(Integer.parseInt(readPort));
        connectionFactory.setChannel(channel);
        connectionFactory.setTransportType(Integer.parseInt(transportType));
    } catch (NumberFormatException | JMSException e) {
        log.error(e.toString(),e);
    }
    return connectionFactory;
}

@Bean
public Destination jmsDestinationResolverSender() throws JMSException {
    return new MQQueue(updateQueue);
}

@Bean
public Destination jmsDestinationResolverReceiver() throws JMSException {
    return new MQQueue(replyQueue);
}

@Bean
public Destination jmsDestinationResolverReplyTo() throws JMSException {
    return new MQQueue(queueGateway, replyQueue);
}

@Bean
public JmsTemplate jmsQueueTemplate(SingleConnectionFactory oSingleConnectionFactory) throws JMSException {
    JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate();
    jmsTemplate.setConnectionFactory(oSingleConnectionFactory);
    jmsTemplate.setDefaultDestination(jmsDestinationResolverSender());
    jmsTemplate.afterPropertiesSet();

    log.info("in jms configuration ConnectionFactory is:" + jmsTemplate.getConnectionFactory());
    log.info("in jms configuration Send destination is:" + jmsTemplate.getDefaultDestination());
    log.info("in jms configuration Send Delivery Delay is :" + jmsTemplate.getDeliveryDelay());
    log.info("in jms configuration Send Delivery Mode is:" + jmsTemplate.getDeliveryMode());

    return jmsTemplate;
}

@Bean
public DefaultMessageListenerContainer listenerContainer() throws JMSException {
    DefaultMessageListenerContainer defMsgListCont = new DefaultMessageListenerContainer();
    defMsgListCont.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory3());
    defMsgListCont.setDestination(jmsDestinationResolverReceiver());
    defMsgListCont.setMessageListener(messageListenerReciever1);
    defMsgListCont.afterPropertiesSet();
    return defMsgListCont;
}

@Bean
public DefaultMessageListenerContainer listenerContainer2() throws JMSException {
    DefaultMessageListenerContainer defMsgListCont = new DefaultMessageListenerContainer();
    defMsgListCont.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory2());
    defMsgListCont.setDestination(jmsDestinationResolverReceiver());
    defMsgListCont.setMessageListener(messageListenerReciever2);
    defMsgListCont.afterPropertiesSet();
    return defMsgListCont;
}   

  // Serialize message content to json using TextMessage
  @Bean
  public MessageConverter jacksonJmsMessageConverter() {
    MappingJackson2MessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2MessageConverter();
    converter.setTargetType(MessageType.TEXT);
    converter.setTypeIdPropertyName("_type");
    return converter;
  }
```

}

I am not sure where is the issue, But i strongly beleive its related to connection factory i am using , I am trying to use CachingConnectionFactory  , But with below mentioend configuration it keeps sporadically failing with below code exception at this line

```
jmsQueueTemplate.send(mc);
```

Exceptiopn below :

```
> 12-12-2018 09:05:27.153  INFO htappp22 --- [     FAPS-FOS-5] c.a.f.s.FHSeqAssignOrRemoveServiceImpl   : JMSException while Sending Message To FOS Outside
org.springframework.jms.UncategorizedJmsException: Uncategorized exception occurred during JMS processing; nested exception is javax.jms.JMSException: MQJMS2007: failed to send message to MQ queue; nested exception is com.ibm.mq.MQException: MQJE001: Completion Code 2, Reason 2009
    at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsUtils.convertJmsAccessException(JmsUtils.java:316)
    at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.convertJmsAccessException(JmsAccessor.java:169)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:487)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.send(JmsTemplate.java:559)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.send(JmsTemplate.java:550)
    at com.aa.faps.services.FHSeqAssignOrRemoveServiceImpl.crewSeqAssignOrRemoveBatch(FHSeqAssignOrRemoveServiceImpl.java:115)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionInterceptor$1.call(AsyncExecutionInterceptor.java:115)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.jms.JMSException: MQJMS2007: failed to send message to MQ queue
    at com.ibm.mq.jms.services.ConfigEnvironment.newException(ConfigEnvironment.java:567)
    at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQMessageProducer.sendInternal(MQMessageProducer.java:1743)
    at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQMessageProducer.send(MQMessageProducer.java:1056)
    at org.springframework.jms.connection.CachedMessageProducer.send(CachedMessageProducer.java:181)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.jms.connection.CachedMessageProducer$Jms2MessageProducerInvocationHandler.invoke(CachedMessageProducer.java:293)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy276.send(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.doSend(JmsTemplate.java:626)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.doSend(JmsTemplate.java:597)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate$3.doInJms(JmsTemplate.java:562)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:484)
    ... 15 more
```

Comment: Do you know what error the queue manager gets in the AMQERR01.LOG around the time frame when you get an error?

Comment: where can i find that log, we are just consuming a MQ channel which is maintained by some other team, everything was fine, till I changed connection factory to connectioncachingfactory.

Comment: prior to connectioncachingfactory you were likely connecting and disconnecting for each message, now you keep the connection open longer and it may be timing out.  The log mentioned would need to be reviewed by the MQ Admin team to provide you with the information.  What version of MQ jar files are you using with spring?

Comment: The error message `MQJMS2007: failed to send message to MQ queue; nested exception is com.ibm.mq.MQException: MQJE001: Completion Code 2, Reason 2009` indicates you are running MQ v6.0 or less.  6.0 went out of support September 2012.  More importantly MQ channel connection reliability has been improved.  Starting at MQ v7.0 channels use bidirectional heart beats.  When the heart beat interval is set to a appropriate value this is good at keeping the connections active.

Comment: You can look at the version by checking the version with this command `unzip -p com.ibm.mq.jar META-INF/MANIFEST.MF|grep Implementation-Version`.  Also check with your MQ admin to see what version the queue manager is at.  Find out for the SVRCONN channel you connect to what the values are of the following: `HBINT` and `SHARECNV`.

Comment: Thanks, Josh for responding, I looked in to manifest we are using Implementation-Version: 6.0.1.1 - j600-101-060504 . Not sure, What exactly I am missing in JMS and CachingConnectionFactory Configuration

Comment: Upgraded to a more recent version of MQ client jar files.  Without queue manager logs there is not much else to tell you. Answer the other questions above about the QM version and channel settings.